# FirebaseUI "Sign in with email" does nothing when tapped

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, firebaseui

I have the following code taken directly from [this blog](https://blog.techchee.com/add-sign-in-with-firebaseui-in-swiftui-app/). This code successfully displays the FirebaseUI with Google sign In, Apple sign In, and Email sign in when I place the `SignInViewUI` into my view.

Google and Apple sign in both function correctly. **Email sign in does nothing when tapped.**

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI
import SwiftUI
typealias AM = AuthManager
class AuthManager : NSObject{
       
    static let shared = AuthManager()

    var authViewController : UIViewController {
        return MyAuthViewController(authUI: FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!)
    }
    
    init(withNavigationBar : Bool = false){
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        super.init()
        self.setupProviders()
    }
    
    private func setupProviders(){
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
            FUIGoogleAuth.init(authUI: authUI),
            FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider(),
            FUIEmailAuth()]
        authUI.providers = providers
    }
}

extension AuthManager {
    // an optional handler closure for error handling
    func signOut(onError handler : ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil ){
        do {
            try FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.signOut()
            if let handler = handler {
                handler(nil)
            }
        }
        catch (let err){
            if let handler = handler {
                handler(err)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func isSignedIn() -> Bool {
        if let _ = Firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser{
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

extension AuthManager {
    func setAuthDelegate(_ delegate : FUIAuthDelegate){
        FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.delegate = delegate
    }
}

class MyAuthViewController : FUIAuthPickerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scrollView = view.subviews[0]
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
        let contentView = scrollView.subviews[0]
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}


struct SignInViewUI: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SignInViewUI>) ->
        UIViewController {
        return AM.shared.authViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController,
               context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SignInViewUI>) {
        // empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is something to do with a navigation controller being required for the Email sign in, based on the final comment on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/319).

Surrounding the `SignInViewUI` in a `NavigationView` allows the button to work.

Secondly, the `FirebaseApp.configure()` line must be removed from the `AuthManager` and placed into the `AppDelegate` `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ...` method.